# Duplicate source folder when creating a maven web project

Tags: java, maven, webproject

When I am trying to create a new web application project using maven, I am getting duplicate src folder in the project directory structure. Is it expected or I am doing anything wrong?

If it is expected why is it creating two directories with the same name, Is there any specific reason?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not creating two directories with the same name. Just check with your explorer, or the command line.

It's just Eclipse showing two different views (one as a directory of the project, one as a Java resource directory) of the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

They both are same. Only thing is your IDE is showing first one in Java build path format and other one as normal. If you go to folder structure you would notice that they are physically same path.

This happens when the folder structure in the build path.

But still since your IDE is differentiating them, use the first one in the picture -> src/main/resources